# How to detect new lines from a Json text in Java, Android

Tags: java, android, newline

The text is received from a Json is like this:

> ```
> This is sentence 1.
>
> This is <b>sentence 2</b>.
> ```

I don't know how to detect that empty space in java/Android.

I want to replace the new lines from the Json with `<br/>` because I'm trying to find a workaround to this problem: [Android, format text from Json to HTML removes new lines and white spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68429167/android-format-text-from-json-to-html-removes-new-lines-and-white-spaces)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the Json text had \r\n inside that I did not see, and I just had to use:

```
jsonText.replace("\r\n", "<br/>");
```

The json is extracted from a MySql database. I could see `\r\n` special characters only when I did a sql export from PHPmyAdmin.